# What is ElasticProperty - OmitNorms equivalent in Nest 5.5.0 Version

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have recently updated from version 1.9.2 to 5.5.0. It resulted in many compilation errors because of breaking changes and most of them I could fix following documentation on https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/docs/2.0-breaking-changes/nest-breaking-changes.md.

However I am still not able to find the replacement for

```
[ElasticProperty(OmitNorms = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
```

Could anyone please help me here.

Tia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NEST 5.x, `OmitNorms=true` would be

```
public class Message
{
    [Keyword(Norms=false)]
    public Content { get; set; }
}
```

The [`keyword` datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/keyword.html) is not analyzed and the `Norms` property controls whether [norms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/norms.html) are enabled.